# How to select checkbox in ListView from code - WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, checkbox, binding

I have a ListView with checkboxes like this:

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="usersListView"
    Width="300"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    SelectionChanged="childrenListView_SelectionChanged"
    Background="{StaticResource BackgroundPrimaryBrush}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}"
    Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Tag="{Binding Id}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullName}" Header="Name" Width="250"/>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

All checkboxes in ListView are from List 'AllUsers' from database.
Now I want to set specific checkboxes to IsChecked=True in code behind.
I have another List 'Children' which have only few of the 'AllUsers' elements.
What I want is to display ListView with selected checkboxed binded to Persons in 'Children'.

I tried to implement this by myself with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented class wrapper to Person but I couldn't get Binding properly with this.

I hope I did explain the problem properly.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Set the Id property of the items you want to select to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a IMultiValueConverter.

In the example below, my **Children** object is a simple string with the name. I have two list, the **AllChildrens** list and the **SelectedChildrens** list.

Foreach element in the **AllChildrens** collection, the converter checks if the element is contained into **SelectedChildrens** collection.

XAML: (I've removed the events)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllChildrens}" Tag="{Binding SelectedChildrens}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:IEnumerableContainsConverter x:Key="Contains" />
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}">
                                <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Contains}">
                                        <Binding Path="." />
                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}" Path="Tag" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullName}" Header="Name" Width="250"/>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class Model
{
    public Model()
    {
        AllChildrens = new List<string>()
        {
            "James",
            "Annabelle",
            "Kevin",
            "William",
            "Joseph",
        };

        SelectedChildrens = new List<string>()
        {
            "James",
            "Annabelle",
            "William",
        };
    }

    public List<string> AllChildrens { get; set; }
    public List<string> SelectedChildrens { get; set; }
}
```

Converter:

```
class IEnumerableContainsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null &&
            values.Length == 2 &&
            values[0] is string current_children && // Replace with your children object type
            values[1] is IEnumerable<string> selected) // Replace with your children object type
        {
            return selected.Contains(current_children);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```